# 3DS Max - Empty motion panel

Tags: user-interface, animation, motion, 3dsmax

I'm currently using 3DS Max 2017 and I created a CAT using the base human model and adjust it to my 3D model.

Now I'd like to animate that CAT but once selected, there's nothing shown in the Motion panel...

I'm totally new to 3DS Max and might be doing something stupid :|

Here's a screen showing what I explained : [image: No content in motion panel]

Could you explain me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Biped (Create > Systems > Biped) in the viewport and check if the Motion panel shows the Biped Parameters. If its not, then resetting the program to default settings might help.
Follow [this link](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Resetting-3ds-Max-3ds-Max-Design.html) to reset user settings.